# How to fix jagged poor quality text and icons on my 1080p 27inch external monitor connected to laptop through HDMI

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, external-display

Monitor: BenQ GW2780 1080p

Overall picture quality is fine, but the icons and text are really horrible and painful to the eyes. Text is not blurry or dull, it's actually sharp and bright, but also jagged and distorted looking like 0 anti-aliasing.

I tried connecting this monitor to two laptops one by one: 1920x1080 with HDMI and 1366x768 with VGA, text quality looks bad with both of them.

Things I have tried:

1. Already checked the correct resolution for each display.
2. Synced their refresh rates. My monitor was running at 59hz for some reason. Changed it to 60p hz which was same as my laptop. Nothing happened.
3. Callibrated with clearType text settings.
4. Used settings to make text larger. Text appears bigger less painful to eyes but still jagged.
5. Scaled DPI settings but same effect as 4.
6. Downloaded manufacturers drivers from website and installed.

I know it's not a natural issue of "big screen with low resolution gives bad quality" because I have used another 27" 1080p Acer monitor in my office connected to a 1366x768 resolution laptop through VGA cable and text looked great.(picture quality slightly worse than my monitor though which I don't mind).

Desperately looking for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same monitor. Decrease the sharpness setting on the monitor to about 2. It worked for me.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1104340)

Comment: Well I don't know how to better answer that but adjusting the sharpness setting on the monitor did it for me.

Comment: C'mon guys, delete votes? You cannot be serious. This answer sounds very plausible. Perhaps add where to find this setting, Ronald.